# Having a False Conclusion with a True Premise

Tags: logic

I recently started Geometry. The class said that if a premise was true in an if statement, then the conclusion had to be true. This makes sense on a basic level. Take this for example:

> If a = b and c = b, then a = c if a = 2, b = 2, and c = 2.

We have a true premise (a = b and c = b), so we conclude that the conclusion is true (a = c).

However, what if I did something like this:

> If a = b and c = b, then a = c + 2 if a = 2, b = 2, and c = 2.

I still have a true premise, but my conclusion isn't true.

My question, then, is how can someone be sure that their conclusion is true? Are all basic premises and conclusions based on inductive reasoning and experience?

In summary, is there a mathematical way to ensure that a conclusion is true?

Comment: The conclusion of a "logically correct" argument is *true* if the premises are.

Comment: In what sense $(a = b \text { and } c = b)$ is a true premise ? If $a=2$ and $b=2$ and $c=3$, it is not true.

Comment: Ok, but now the conclusion is *false* because the argument is *wrong*: if $(a=b=c=2) \text { and } (a=b) \text { and } (b=c)$, then $c+2=4 \ne a$.

Comment: We can specify what "logically correct" means, but in an arithmetical context it means also to use the correct rules of opeartions : sum, etc.

Comment: We have correct rules of *logic*, like e.g: "if every man is mortal and Socrates is a men, then Socrtaes is mortal", correct rules for the *logic of equality*, like *transitivity*: "if $(a=b)$ and $(b=c)$, then $(a=c)$", and *substitution*: "if $(a=b)$, then $(f(a)=f(b))$".

Comment: In arithmetic, we apply *transitivity* deriving from $(a=2)$ and $(c=2)$ that $(a=c)$ and from this, applying *substitution*, we derive $(a+2=c+2)$.

Comment: Lookup "rules of inference"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excellent question! You have just the right mindset here of a good logician.  And yes, the whole area of logic, in particular formal logic (or symbolic logic, or mathematical logic) is devoted to laying out and distinguishing between just those inferences that you can make, and those that you cannot. Or, as logicians say: those inferences that are *valid* versus those that are not.

There are *many* online resources to learn more about this ([here is one](http://www.philosophypages.com/lg/index.htm), and in particular follow their page on [symbolic logic](http://www.philosophypages.com/lg/e10a.htm)), and I highly encourage you to do so, given your question. Just do a search on 'logic' or 'formal logic', and go from there. I think you'll enjoy it! And, as a bonus, you'll learn about how logic is at the foundation of computers and a good bit of artificial intelligence.

Finally, just to give you a taste, here is a proof created in the Fitch proof system that shows that you can indeed infer $a=c$ from $a=b$ and $c=b$:

[image]

The two rules used here are:

$= \ Intro$ ('Identity Introduction'): every object is identical to itself, and so we can always say that $a=a$ (or $b=b$ or ...)

$= \ Elim$ ('Identity Elimination'): If we know that two objects are identical, then whatever is true of the one, has to be true of the other thing as well. Mathemtaically/formally: if we have $a=b$, and we have some statement involving $a$, then we can substitute any of those $a$'s with $b$'s.

On the other hand, to *disprove* some inference, i.e. to show that you cannot infer $a = c+2$ from $a=b$ and $c=b$, all we need to do is provide a counterexample ... and you yourself provided one: just assume $a=b=c=2$: that will make the premises true, but the conclusion false, and so that tells us that that is an invalid inference.

Answer (score 1):

> In summary, is there a mathematical way to ensure that a conclusion is true?

Yes, by providing a proof. Your original statement of $a = b \wedge b = c \;\rightarrow\;  a = c$ is an assertion, and despite it being true, no proof has been given.

Comment: So, essentially you're saying I am _assuming_ that the statement is true without any actual proof? How would I prove it?

Comment: @WhiteEagle If you're trying to prove something as fundamental as the transitivity of equality over the real numbers it heavily depends on what construction of the real numbers you use. Trying to prove the fundamentals of math is very difficult and painstaking work.

Answer (score 0):

In order for the implication to be valid , if the premise is true, the conclusion must be true.

Otherwise the implication is false.

Apparently the only case in which the implication is false is when the premise is true and the conclusion is false.

Comment: I understand that. How do I _prove_ that the conclusion is true?

Comment: You may use  the true premise, other related theorems, and logic to prove your conclusion. That is called a proof.